# How to test whether numpy array slice is a copy in multidim case?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, copy

According to [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.copies.html), advanced indexing is supposed to return a copy of the array. This works as expected in the one-dim case. However, if array is multidimensional, then numpy does not recognize it as a copy. How can I test whether a copy or view is returned in multidim case if I don't have access to the original array?

Example:

```
import numpy as np

y = np.ones((1, 10))
b = y[:, [0, 5, 6]]

# b is not a copy
assert not b.flags['OWNDATA']
assert b.base is not None
```

But it actually is a copy

```
b[:] = 33
print(y)
```

Comment: Look at `b.strides` and `b.base`.  It isn't a `view` of `a`.  It's a `view` of something else, an intermediate array created during the indexing.  That indexing is somewhat complicated, but usually we don't need to know the details.  I stumbled on this by accident after years of answering SO numpy questions.  Strictly speaking `b` does not have a record of what `a` was.

Comment: Why do you need a test? Don't you know what kind of indexing you did?  Keep in mind that `a` might be a view of something else.  E.g. a common test array is `a=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)`. `a.base` is not None.

Comment: thanks, I was just hoping to ensure it is safe to change variables of the class in-place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets make `y` a bit more interesting:

```
In [915]: y = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5);y, y.base
Out[915]: 
(array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

It is a `view` of a 1d array.

Now use advanced indexing:

```
In [916]: b = y[:,[0,2,4]];b, b.base
Out[916]: 
(array([[0, 2, 4],
        [5, 7, 9]]),
 array([[0, 5],
        [2, 7],
        [4, 9]]))

In [917]: b.strides, b.base.strides
Out[917]: ((4, 8), (8, 4))
```

`b` is a (2,3) array, as we expect from the indexing, but it is actually a transpose of a (3,2) array.  Evidently `numpy` is selecting values using the list index, the 2nd dimension, and putting the slice dimension last.  Then it transposes to get the desired shape.  This hints at why mixing advanced and basic indexing can produce unexpected shapes (as documented and explained in other SO).

In any case, I don't see a way of testing `b` to verify it isn't a `view` of `y` - except by comparing the `base` attributes.  The simplest thing is to accept the documentation's claim that it is a copy - just not a 'direct' copy.

We could get the same array with basic indexing - and get a `view` of `y.base`:

```
In [918]: c = y[:,::2]; c, c.base
Out[918]: 
(array([[0, 2, 4],
        [5, 7, 9]]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

A couple of other ways of getting a simple copy:

```
In [924]: d = y[[0,1], ::2]; d, d.base
Out[924]: 
(array([[0, 2, 4],
        [5, 7, 9]]),
 None)

In [925]: d = y[[[0],[1]], [0,2,4]]; d, d.base
Out[925]: 
(array([[0, 2, 4],
        [5, 7, 9]]),
 None)
```